# Manual installation of a ruby gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, embedded-linux

This might sound a bit weird, but (as the title suggests) i need to install an application (and all its dependencies), which is distributed as a ruby gem, **without** actually using "gem install ..." or anything like that.

The reason is that i want to run that application on an embedded linux system (built using buildroot), which doesn't have any way for me to actually install applications.
Anything i want on the target has to be compiled and "installed" (i.e. copied to the image of the root file system) as part of the build process on the host system.
The target system also doesn't have a compiler, so if the gem contains any C code, it needs to be compiled on the host system using the cross compilation toolchain.

Some additional information, even though it probably doesn't matter too much:

- The application in question is asciidoctor-pdf
- The target system is a Cyclone-V SoC (ARM Cortex-A9)

So essentially i need instructions for the equivalent of a "compile from source", but for ruby gems.

Comment: Something along the lines of `bundle install --path vendor/bundle`? By doing that, you can include all dependencies for a project as part of the source control.

Comment: Have you looked at [Ruby Packer](https://github.com/pmq20/ruby-packer)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, at first glance Ruby Packer seems more suitable for my use case, but i'll try out both